# What is the best way to add external languages to android application in runtime

Tags: android, xml, localizable.strings

Our client application has means of updating a "language file" from a server occasionally. Yet it seems quite a challenge to support it on android.. 
I tried using inflate( XmlPullParser, ... ) but later found it doesn't support non-binary XML files.

**The following are given:**

1. Our app uses `@string/resource_id` resources to support languages. Basically it supports English, but the requirement is to provide language resources dynamically. That is, if we need to support Greek, or provide a change to the Greek language texts, we should be able to provide that on runtime.
2. So, on runtime our app connects a service and downloads an XML file, with syntax similar to string.xml in the current language.

**What remains is how to change the text resources in the application in a sane manner (not one by one..)**

I tried using inflate(with the XmlPullParser parameter) but it seems to be intended for use with binary pre-compiled XML files. To use that it would require to binarize the XML before hand, and that would be less compatible, not to say that aapt.exe tool is less documented, especially in my case.

So, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it can be done everywhere in Android but instead of using native resources reference, maybe you can use the Java [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class and using the device locale configuration to retrieve the wanted strings programmatically?

Comment: Seems like a long shot.. How exactly are you suggesting to do this?

Comment: Simply use a Properties instance in which you load an localized InputStream from a file. Then retain this instance in the Application context and access it when you display some text, with myProperties.getProperty(key).